# Visual Studio IDE Preview 2022 for Mac M1 - Keyboard Shortcuts Dont Work After Modified - The Key Combination has Conflicts

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Once I changed the keyboard shortcuts, all shortcuts including operating system defaults (like CMD + , for Preferences) stopped working. All I get now every time I press them is `the key combination () has conflicts`. I open the window with the conflicts, and it says 0.
[image]

Have you guys encountered this error? How did you fix it?
Visual Studio IDE exact version (I just updated today March 16th 2022):

```
Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac Preview
Version 17.0 Preview (17.0 build 8001)
Installation UUID: 2372e321-d894-4a2e-895c-05397cf15755

Runtime
.NET 6.0.2-servicing.1.22101.5 (64-bit)
Architecture: Arm64

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.1.0-3.22075.3+592501cbb9c9394072a245c15b3458ff88155d85

NuGet
Version: 6.0.0.262

.NET SDK (Arm64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.201/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    6.0.201
    6.0.200
MSBuild SDKs: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.201/Sdks

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK Versions:
    3.1.417
    3.1.416

.NET Core Runtime (Arm64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    6.0.3
    6.0.2

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.7.0.0
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 13.3 (20102)
Build 13E113

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 8.6.0.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: caa899d24
Branch: d17-1
Build date: 2022-01-16 21:16:56-0500

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.6.0.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: caa899d24
Branch: d17-1
Build date: 2022-01-16 21:16:56-0500

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.1.5.29
Hash: 631c9091b
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-0-vsmac
Build date: 2022-03-11 17:25:57 UTC

Xamarin.Android
Version: 12.2.99.125 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/main/b3cb3a9
Android SDK: /Users/scientist/Library/Android/sdk
    Supported Android versions:
        12.0 (API level 31)
        11.0 (API level 30)
        10.0 (API level 29)
        9.0  (API level 28)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 5.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 32.0.0
SDK Build Tools Version: 33.0.0 rc1

Build Information: 
Mono: f34bd77
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/main@cbd96668
ProGuard: Guardsquare/proguard/v7.0.1@912d149
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.0@ccd83d8
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@f0b3abd

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.12
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.2.0.23
Hash: ac7b2f4
Branch: remotes/origin/jonp-bump-at-c5729b16~1
Build date: 2022-03-11 17:26:01 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1102
Hash: 70060c2
Branch: remotes/origin/HEAD~1
Build date: 2022-03-11 17:26:01 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 1700008001
Git revision: 64fe256db3b9f472065f8df46220cffb52a07cde
Build date: 2022-03-11 17:23:36+00
Build branch: release-17.0
Build lane: release-17.0

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.3.0
Darwin 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0
    Mon Feb 21 20:36:53 PST 2022
    root:xnu-8020.101.4~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is exactly an answer to the problem or the proper way to fix it in the way you're looking for, but I've been fighting with this problem this morning. Force killing visual studio `CMD + Q` and then re-opening the IDE/solution fixed the issue for me.

Comment: At the time, I did try to kill it and re-open, but nothing happened. Recently another update was released, maybe this one has done something, but I have not used this IDE since I have had this issue. I would not know. Now that I opened the IDE it seems to work, however even when I had this issue it took a little time to break the keyboard shortcuts. In essence, because it works right now, I am still not convinced until I daily drive it successfully again.

Comment: What are you using in the meantime, VS Code? I also just applied an update to VS for mac... hopefully the IDE is stable soon, it's been constant problems for me.

Comment: I happen to have a licence available for Rider at work (https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/). Very pleased with this IDE.

Comment: Perhaps I'll make a purchase, a friend of mine uses it and speaks highly of it as well.